# Querying for isodate/datetime to Mongodb in RobotFramework with Robotframework-MongoDB-Library

Tags: mongodb, datetime, robotframework, isodate

I am using Robotframework-MongoDB-Library in Robotframework to automate some Mongodb tests using python3.7 (rf version 3.1.2 installed via pip3). I have managed to get RF to connect to Mongodb and run some of the basic tests like:

```
Connect To MongoDB    ${MDBHost}    ${MDBPort}
@{allCollections}   Get MongoDB Collections mydbname
Log Many    @{allCollections}
```

However I need to do some queries based on dates like the following

```
${all_results}  Retrieve Some MongoDB Records   ivoox  impressionsByProgram   {"d" : ISODate("2019-09-30T22:00:00.000Z")}
```

Which results in "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 8 (char 7)". Looking for answers it seems that as the mongoLibrary is using PyMongo, I need to use datetime instead of Isodate, but I get the same error:

```
 ${all_results}  Retrieve Some MongoDB Records   ivoox  impressionsByProgram   {"d" : datetime(2019,30,1)}
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 8 (char 7)

Further search have pointed me to having Bson installed or not but I have verified I have installed modules in right order, first Bson and then PyMongo via pip3 in both cases.

MongoLibrary has been also installed using pip3.

Any ideas

Comment: You mean [this library](https://github.com/iPlantCollaborativeOpenSource/Robotframework-MongoDB-Library)? A quick browse through the code shows that the type conversions necessary for BSON date are not supported. The library appears to have had little to no maintenance, and appears to be small effort added by an individual many years ago.

Comment: The correct way to convert presented JSON into a valid "Python" expression for the underlying driver would be to use the [`json_util`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) module from the pymongo distribution. You could always patch it yourself.

Comment: @NeilLunn, the Library has been forked and updated to python3 in https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-mongodb-library/ but basically that's the library. It is the "official" library in RobotFramework to deal with Mongo, that's why I am using it. Unfortunately I am not skilled in python to patch the library; testing in RF does not require high coding skills